# OpenLDAP - Saves userPassword as PlainText

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am setting up openLDAP for one of my Java applications. Usernames and passwords are stored in openLDAP and users are able to update their passwords via the application (using the javax.naming.directory API'). I imported our users from our existing Sun Directory Server into openLDAP. Import was successfull and passwords were encrypted in SSHA format. I noticed that when i update a password from the application, it stores it in 'Plain Text' format. I can unhide the password when i view it via Apache Directory Studio. A lot of googling later, i tried setting the "password-hash {SSHA}" in the slapd.conf file and that didn't help me either. I am on a windows environment. I am passing the password to openLDAP in plain text format. There is no encryption going on in the code. I  know i can encrypt it in the application but i would prefer openLDAP to do it for me. Please let me know if i can do anything on the openLDAP side.

This is the JAVA code i use today to modify passwords. This has been working fine in our existing environment for the past 7 years.

```
ModificationItem[] newAttribs = new ModificationItem[1];
Attribute passwordAttrib = new BasicAttribute(DirectoryConstants.USER_PASSWORD, password);
ModificationItem passwordItem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, passwordAttrib);
newAttribs[0] = passwordItem;

.....
DirContext ctx = this.getContext();
ctx.modifyAttributes( DirectoryConstants.USER_UID + "=" + userId + "," + ou, newAttribs);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the default password hash format in openldap is SSHA, which is nice.
Unfortunately, the default password policy in openldap is 'do not enforce password hashing'.

You will want to add an overlay to the database you're storing users in.
In the cn=config version, this looks like, approximately:

```
dn: olcOverlay={X}ppolicy,olcDatabase={Y}bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcPPolicyConfig
olcOverlay: {X}ppolicy
olcPPolicyHashCleartext: TRUE
```

(where Y is your database number in cn=config, X is the overlay number you want it to be)

The slapd.conf version is similar, you need an:

```
overlay ppolicy
ppolicy_hash_cleartext
```

entry, inside the relevant database definition (you don't need to provide a value for ppolicy_hash_cleartext, presence indicates TRUE).

Comment: And if he's using the password policy overlay he will also need to use the extended password modify operation.